# is there -P cmd arg to java?

Tags: java, cmd, system, parameters

I know there when I run this cmd:

`java -Dparam=1 ...`

means that there is a system property named `"param" with value "1"`
but what does `-P` mean?

`java -Pparam=1 ...`

I saw this in code, but couldn't google it.

Comment: `man java` says **no**, can you post a complete *runnable* example?

Comment: Everything after JVM options on command line is passed to main method as string array ...

Comment: Not according to [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html).

Answer (score 2):

I think this is just used by the program running in the JVM (as a normal startparameter).